# How to add extra file or directory while Rebar3 compiling?

Tags: erlang, rebar3

Currently I have a rebar3 project, and I want to use another file for my application configuration. The configuration file is called `appConfig.conf` under `conf` directory. I tried to use relative path to access the configuration file, however rebar3 didn't put conf directory under `_build` directory, which leads to `file not found` error.

The directory structure is like this:

```
conf/
include/
src/
```

How can I make rebar3 consider `conf` directory while compiling?

Answer (score 1):

I am using rebar3 profiles when I need different config files for production or test mode

Structure

```
_build
config
priv
src
```

Here is the part of the rebar.config file

```
{profiles, [
  {production,
    [{relx, [
      {dev_mode,      false},
      {include_erts,  true},
      {include_src,   false},
      {vm_args,       "config/production/vm.args"},
      {sys_config,    "config/production/sys.config"}]
    }]
  },
  {test,
    [{relx, [
      {erl_opts, [{native, o3}]},
      {dev_mode,      false},
      {include_erts,  true},
      {include_src,   false},
      {vm_args,       "config/test/vm.args"},
      {sys_config,    "config/test/sys.config"}]
    }]
  }
]}
```

Comment: This is the way I recommend this is done as a rebar3 maintainer.